# Is anyone else seeing 502 errors with Civicrm 4.7.4.?

Tags: upgrade, error, 4.7

We recently updated to 4.7.4 in an attempt to resolve some issues we were facing, in the end we found another fix for that problem.

But since the update we have been experiencing 502 Bad Gateway ("The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.") errors, they seem to randomly occur on any pages that use Civi but not on any of the normal Wordpress pages in the site.

Our Civi install sits behind a haproxy load balancer so its possible this is concealing the true cause of the issues and error messages.

Has anybody else experienced any issues like this on 4.7.4. or any of the other recent versions? As I said the 502 could be a misdirect from our load balancer so other suggestions as to causes would be equally appreciated.

Any suggestions as to causes would be appreciated as I'm drawing a blank myself!

Comment: I've been seeing this in a local dev environment on some pages, yes. Haven't bothered to dig since it didn't get in my way, but the common thread seems to be screens which make an HTTP request (eg civicrm/dashboard, civicrm/admin/extensions). Don't let me lead you astray though - your haproxy / nginx / apache / PHP logs should have information that will help you track the problem down.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought but the environment its deployed in doesn't have the level of granular logging control I need, atleast not on the production server, in the end I rolled back to the last good version I had from last week and will investigate this again as and when I have time to redo it on the test environment.